# Invoking CmdLet from a C#-based PSCmdLet, providing input and capturing output

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm building a Powershell CmdLet for awesome printing. It should function just like `Out-Print` but with all the bells and whistles of [winprint](https://tig.github.io/winprint).

```bsh
PS> get-help out-winprint
NAME
    Out-WinPrint

SYNTAX
    Out-WinPrint [[-Name] <string>] [-SheetDefintion <string>] [-ContentTypeEngine <string>]
    [-InputObject <psobject>] [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    wp
```

For this to work, I need to take the input stream (`InputObject`) of my `PSCmdLet` implementation and pass it through `Out-String` so it's all expanded and formatted. I'm thinking the best way to do this is to use `CommandInvocationIntrinsics.InvokeScript` to invoke `out-string`, which should give me the output as a string...

```cs
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            if (InputObject == null || InputObject == AutomationNull.Value) {
                return;
            }

            IDictionary dictionary = InputObject.BaseObject as IDictionary;
            if (dictionary != null) {
                // Dictionaries should be enumerated through because the pipeline does not enumerate through them.
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary) {
                    ProcessObject(PSObject.AsPSObject(entry));
                }
            }
            else {
                ProcessObject(InputObject);
            }

        }

        private void ProcessObject(PSObject input) {

            object baseObject = input.BaseObject;

            // Throw a terminating error for types that are not supported.
            if (baseObject is ScriptBlock ||
                baseObject is SwitchParameter ||
                baseObject is PSReference ||
                baseObject is PSObject) {
                ErrorRecord error = new ErrorRecord(
                    new FormatException("Invalid data type for Out-WinPrint"),
                    DataNotQualifiedForWinprint,
                    ErrorCategory.InvalidType,
                    null);

                this.ThrowTerminatingError(error);
            }

            _psObjects.Add(input);
        }

        protected override async void EndProcessing() {
            base.EndProcessing();

            //Return if no objects
            if (_psObjects.Count == 0) {
                return;
            }

            var text = this.SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(@"Out-String", true, PipelineResultTypes.None, _psObjects, null);

            // Just for testing...
            this.WriteObject(text, false);
     ...
```

Assume I invoked my cmdlet like this:

```bsh
PS> get-help out-winprint -full | out-winprint`
```

If I understand how this is supposed to work, the var `text` above should be a `string` and `WriteObject` call should display what `out-string` would display (namely the result of `get-help out-winprint -full`).

However, in reality `text` is `string[] = { "" }` (an array of strings with one element, an empty string).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two very small things wrong:

The method is called `InvokeScript` so literally what you're passing is a `scriptblock`.

Right now, your `ScriptBlock` is basically like this:

```
$args = @(<random stuff>) # this line is implicit of course, 
                          # and $args will have the value of whatever your _psObjects has

Out-String
```

So as you can tell the arguments made it to the script, you're just not using them. So you want something a bit more like this instead as your script:

```
Out-String -InputObject $args
```

Only now the problem is that `Out-String` doesn't actually like being given a `Object[]` as an `-InputObject` so instead your script has to be something like:

```
$args | Out-String
```

Or some variation of that like using a `foreach`, you get the idea.

Your second error is that you're passing `_psObjects` onto the wrong parameter - it should be:

```
this.SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(<ScriptBlock>, true, PipelineResultTypes.None, null, _psObjects);
```

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.invokescript?view=pscore-6.2.0) is really bad on this and I have absolutely no idea what the other parameter is for.

On one of the overloads is lists:

`input` = Optionall input to the **command**

`args` = Arguments to pass to the **scriptblock**

But on the next overload it says the following:

`input` = The list of objects to use as input to the **script**.

`args` = The array of arguments to the **command**.

All I can tell you is, in my tests it works when I do it as stated. Hope that helps!

For reference, tested and working PS code:

```
function Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    $results = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript('$args | Out-String', $false, "None", $null, "Hello World!")

    foreach ($item in $results)
    {
        $item
    }
}

Test
```

**EDIT**

I should add that according to my tests, if you pass something to both `input` and `args` then `$args` will be empty inside the script. Like I said, no actual idea what `input` does at all, just pass `null` to it.

**EDIT 2**

As mentioned by tig, on [PowerShell issue 12137](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12137), whatever gets passed to `input` will be bound to the variable `$input` inside the scriptblock which means either `input` or `args` can be used.

That being said... be careful of using `$input` - it is a collection that will contain more than what is passed via the `input` parameter: according to my tests index 0 will contain a `bool` that is whatever is passed on 2nd parameter of `InvokeScript()` and index 1 will contain a `PipelineResultTypes` that is whatever was passed to `InvokeScript()` on the 3rd parameter.

Also I would not recommend using `PowerShell.Create()` in this case: why create a new instance of PowerShell when you have a `PSCmdlet` which implies you already have one?

I still think using `args`/`$args` is the best solution. Of course you could also make things a lot nicer (although completely unneeded in this case) by using a ScriptBlock like:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [PSObject[]]
    $objects
)

Out-String -InputObject $objects
```

This will be faster as well since you are no longer relying on the (slow) pipeline.

Just don't forget that now you need to wrap your `_psObjects` around an `object[]` like:

```
this.SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(<ScriptBlock>, true, PipelineResultTypes.None, null, new object[] {_psObjects});
```

Comment: Yep. See this Issue that I created and got help on: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12137. Also note that this works using `$input`: `var result = this.SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(@"$input| Out-String", true, PipelineResultTypes.None, _psObjects, null);`.  If you'd update your answer to show all three solutions, I'll mark your answer as the answer (the 3rd solution being the one that uses `CmdletInfo`/`Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)` found in linked Issue.

Comment: There are always 1000% ways to skin a cat, including some that are not listed in that github issue as well. For that purpose as well as the fact that you asked for help with your code and not list ways this can work I will not be including other examples, but I will amend my question to explain the purpose of `input`. Still, I think an issue should be raised for when both `input` and `args` are specified as I do not see why `$args` should then become `null` inside the script.

Comment: And documentation still sucks ;)

Comment: I'd be interested in an update from you to see if using `$input` does also show items [0] and [1] as being the parameters of `InvokeScript()`